# Getting exception when calling method on ViewController before Navigating to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

I am trying to setData on a ViewController Instance before navigating to it.

I am navigating from a nib file to a view controller in another story board.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
- (IBAction)newReferenceButtonPressed {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ReferenceStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    ReferenceViewController *evc = (ReferenceViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReferenceViewController"];

    ReferenceObject *referenceObject = [[ReferenceObject alloc] initWithReference: self.referenceDetailsDictionary[@"getReferenceDetailsResponse"]];

    [evc setClientDetailsWithName:customerNameLabel.text andAddress:address1Label.text];
    [evc setReferenceData:referenceObject];    

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:evc
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

I am making two method calls on the destination view controller. Strangely, setClientDetailsWithName call has no problems while setReferenceData gives me unrecognized selector exception.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please show the definition of `setReferenceData` in ReferenceViewController

Comment: I thing that you have typo in ReferenceVC .m file in case of 'setReferenceData' method